# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: mount, partition, kali-linux

I was using Kali 2020.1 and had two partitions for `/` and `/home`. `/` partition ran out of space, so I did some stupid shit without knowing what i was doing to expand the size of `/` partition. It was not successful. Next time When i power on the machine, it didn't boot. Then I reinstalled Kali onto `/` partition. Now I can't mount the other half of the hard drive which was previously used as `/home`. 
Partition table is as follows,

```
Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type  
/dev/sda1  *        2048  23437311  23435264  11.2G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda2       23439358 976769023 953329666 454.6G  5 Extended  
/dev/sda5       23439360  48373759  24934400  11.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris  
/dev/sda6       48375808 976769023 928393216 442.7G 83 Linux
```

`/dev/sda6` is the partition that I need to mount as I have data in it. `sda2` came to the play once I did that expanding thing :(

I tried to execute

```
mkdir /mnt/mydrive  
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/mydrive
```

Then it gave me the following error,

```
mount: /mnt/mydrive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Appreciate your help.
-*poor noob*-

Comment: If you had two partitions to start with, then you probably had two primary partitions; sda1 and sda2. If you then turned sda2 into an extended partition, as shown in your question, then the original sda2 was destroyed. You can try using `testdisk` to see if it can recover anything: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It worked bro. I recovered all my data. Thanks a lot for the response.